# How to show more web page in a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sample i have two link google.com and youtube.com.
I want to show interface web each 30 seconds in one screen board web page (it's mean in screen board, first show web page google.com, then after 30 seconds, it'll show web page youtube.com, and repeat). Can i use javascript or jquery ?

```html
<html>
<body>
  <!-- Show page google.com-->
  <!-- Show page youtube.com-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This isn't possible on the client side. You can't use AJAX due to CORS restrictions and you can't use an iframe as the domains will have set the `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` header to block third parties spoofing their site, as you seem to want to do.

Comment: show this same slideshow, if can show many page in a screen

Comment: or can use thirdparty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that showing iFrames for Google and YouTube is a good idea, unless you embed a specific video, YouTube will squawk about same-origin issues, same is true for Google.

However aside from the sites your linking, to actually achieve what you are asking (if I have understood the question correctly) I would do this:

```js
var counter = $('#counter');
var count = $(counter).html();
var origCount = count



function tick(){
 count--
  $(counter).html(count)
  if (count == 0 ) {
   toggleIframe()
    count = origCount
  }
}


function toggleIframe(){
 $('iframe').toggle();
}

setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

```css
iframe{
  border:5px solid #333;
}
#counter{
  font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter">10</div>

<div id="iframeContainer">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://laravel.com/"></iframe>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://vuejs.org/" frameborder="0" style="display:none;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry for this convenience i want to know i can add other link  with many iframe and how i do this (sample 5 hyperlinks). Hope advice from you.

Comment: @BrianCrist Do you mean how to add say for example 5 different pages rather than just 2?

Answer (score 0):

based on your comment I have added another answer, this has more comments so hopefully easy to understand.

This version is dynamic, so you can just add more iframes to the list and they will get added into the cycle.

```js
// This is just to display a counter for demo purposes, you can remove this
var counter = $('#counter');

// Set the count of seconds for each iframe to display
var seconds = 5

// this is the current tick, so will count down to 0 then reset to the seconds variable value.
var tick = seconds;

// count the number of iframes on the page.
var iframesCount = $('#iframeContainer').find('.iframe').length;

// hold the current frame to show.
var currentIframe = 0;

// main function that will be run every second (1000 ms)
function run(){
 // decrement the tick by 1
 tick--
  // update the tick counter on screen (just for demo purposes, you can remove this)
  $('#counter').html(tick)
  // if tick is at 0 we need to switch the frame to the next one.
  if (tick === 0 ) {
   // switch frame to the next frame in the list.
    nextIframe(); 
    // reset the tick back to its original value
    tick = seconds;
  }
}

function nextIframe(){
 // check if the current frame is the last one in the list
 if (currentIframe === iframesCount - 1){
  
  // If it is the last in the list, set the current frame to 0 so we begin back at the first frame
   currentIframe = 0;
  }
  else {
  // if the current frame is not the last in the list, then increment the current frame by 1
   currentIframe++
  }
  // run the toggleFrame function to show/hide the respective frames
  toggleIframe();
  
}

function toggleIframe(){
 // hide all the frames
  $('.iframe').hide();
  // show only the frame that matches current frame
  var frame = $('.iframe')[currentIframe]
  $(frame).show();
}

// kick off the main "run" function every 1000 ms (1 second)
setInterval(run, 1000);
```

```css
iframe{
  border:5px solid #555;
  display:none;
}
iframe:nth-child(1){
  display:block;
}

#counter{
  font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="iframeContainer">
  <iframe class="iframe" width="560" height="315" src="https://laravel.com/"></iframe>
  <iframe class="iframe"  width="560" height="315" src="https://vuejs.org/"></iframe>
  <iframe class="iframe"  width="560" height="315" src="https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/"></iframe>
  <iframe class="iframe"  width="560" height="315" src="https://vuejs.org/v2/api/"></iframe>
  
  <!-- Try to uncomment the below iframe and it should automatically get included in the cycle -->
  <!--<iframe class="iframe"  width="560" height="315" src="https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/"></iframe>-->
</div>

<!-- You can delete the below, its just for demo -->
<div id="counter"></div>



<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```